# UPDATE statement for Joined tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm an SQL Server developer who is working with Oracle for the first time.  And I'm having trouble with an UPDATE statement that I can easily build in SQL server.

Say I have a Table T1 with columns KeyVal1, Keyval2, KeyVal3, NonKeyVal1, ...
KeyVal1 2 and 3 are a compound Key.

I also have table T2 with a Foreign Key relationship to T1's compound key.  I want to update T1.NonKeyVal1 and T1.NonKeyVal2 if the record exists in T2.

In T-SQL I would write:

```
Update T1
Set    NonKeyVal1 = 'x',
       NonKeyVal2 = 'y'
FROM   T1
JOIN   T2 ON T1.KeyVal1 = T2.KeyVal1 AND 
             T1.KeyVal2 = T2.KeyVal2 AND 
             T1.KeyVal3 = T2.KeyVal3;
```

But I'm having trouble figuring this out in Oracle SQL.  Can anyone help, please?

Comment: you can write it in sql server and do a linked server to oracle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
Update T1
Set    NonKeyVal1 = 'x',
       NonKeyVal2 = 'y'
FROM   T1 WHERE EXISTS (
SELECT 1 FROM T2 WHERE T1.KeyVal1 = T2.KeyVal1 AND 
             T1.KeyVal2 = T2.KeyVal2 AND 
             T1.KeyVal3 = T2.KeyVal3);
```

Comment: D'oh!   I don't know why I didn't think of this.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to write this as a correlated subquery:

```
update t1
set    nonkeyval1 = 'x'
where  exists (select null
               from   t2
               where  t1.keyval1 = t2.keyval1
               and    t1.keyval2 = t2.keyval2
               and    t1.keyval3 = t3.keyval3);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are updating T1 based on values in T2 that you join to on certain columns, then in Oracle you can write an updateable view if the join columns are guaranteed to be unique by constraints on the table.

So if there is a unique or primary key constraint on keyval1, keyval2, and keyval3 you could write ...

```
Update (
  select t1.NonKeyVal1 t1_NonKeyVal1,
         t1.NonKeyVal2 t1_NonKeyVal2,
         t2.NonKeyVal1 t2_NonKeyVal1,
         t2.NonKeyVal2 t2_NonKeyVal2
  from   t1 join t2 on (
           T1.KeyVal1 = T2.KeyVal1 AND 
           T1.KeyVal2 = T2.KeyVal2 AND 
           T1.KeyVal3 = T2.KeyVal3))
set t1_NonKeyVal1 = t2_NonKeyVal1,
    t1_NonKeyVal2 = t2_NonKeyVal1;
```

Your case being a little more simple you could:

```
Update (
  select t1.NonKeyVal1,
         t1.NonKeyVal2
  from   t1 join t2 on (
           T1.KeyVal1 = T2.KeyVal1 AND 
           T1.KeyVal2 = T2.KeyVal2 AND 
           T1.KeyVal3 = T2.KeyVal3))
set NonKeyVal1 = 'x',
    NonKeyVal2 = 'y';
```

If there is no constraint then there used to be an unofficial workaround that used an undocumented optimiser hint to bypass the update join cardinality check, but it wasn't very safe.

Nowadays in the absence of a constraint you could use a MERGE statement if you need to reference values from the join table, or as your case is more simple the correlated subquery suggested by others is adequate.